Aiogram работа с inline_query
У меня есть код
@dp.inline_query()

он содержит

articles = [

            types.InlineQueryResultArticle(
                id=result_id_attestat,
                title='Аттестат: ',
                input_message_content=types.InputTextMessageContent(
                    message_text=f'Получаю...'
                )
            ),
            types.InlineQueryResultArticle(
                id=result_id_raspisanie,
                title='Расписание: ',
                input_message_content=types.InputTextMessageContent(
                    message_text='кактой текст'
                )
            )
        ]

получение данных которые должно содержать сообщение занимает время
как сначала отправить сообщение Получаю... а после изменить его на содержимое с подгруженными данными
учитывайте что inline_query может быть отправлен из любого чата не только в чате самого бота
